# How to find Largest Prime Number, Smallest Factor except 1, Sum of Numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

Herro, Um I'm not sure if this is how you use this site but uh lets get to it... So I need help on  this project and I have to do this -

Input        [][]  Output

A - F   ->      Multiply by 3, Divide by 4

G - J       ->          Divide by 3 + 25

K - N      ->   Find Greatest Factor * 2

O - Q     ->        Find largest prime inclusive * 3

R - W      ->   Find Smallest Factor Except 1

X - Z   ->      Sum Numbers

So I was wondering if my first couple is correct, and need help on the empty space. So the Letter represents the number of the as in "Z" is the last letter so its 26,  and "A" is the first so its 1. So if an responses... Thanks ! package Fun;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        run();
    }

    public static void run()
    {
        input();
        evaluateAlphabet();
        evaluate();

    }
    public static void input()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Letter, please");
        x = sc.next();
    }
    public static String x = " ";
    public static int temp = 0;
    public static int answer = 0;

    public static void evaluateAlphabet()
    {   
        if(x.equals("A"))
        {
            temp = 1;
        }
        else if (x.equals("B"))
        {
            temp = 2;
        }
        else if (x.equals("C"))
        {
            temp = 3;
        }
        else if (x.equals("D"))
        {
            temp = 4;
        }
        else if (x.equals("E"))
        {
            temp = 5;
        }
        else if (x.equals("F"))
        {
            temp = 6;
        }
        else if (x.equals("G"))
        {
            temp = 7;
        }
        else if (x.equals("H"))
        {
            temp = 8;
        }
        else if (x.equals("I"))
        {
            temp = 9;
        }
        else if (x.equals("J"))
        {
            temp = 10;
        }
        else if (x.equals("K"))
        {
            temp = 11;
        }
        else if (x.equals("L"))
        {
            temp = 12;
        }
        else if (x.equals("M"))
        {
            temp = 13;
        }
        else if (x.equals("N"))
        {
            temp = 14;
        }
        else if (x.equals("O"))
        {
            temp = 15;
        }
        else if (x.equals("P"))
        {
            temp = 16;
        }
        else if (x.equals("Q"))
        {
            temp = 17;
        }
        else if (x.equals("R"))
        {
            temp = 18;
        }
        else if (x.equals("S"))
        {
            temp = 19;
        }
        else if (x.equals("T"))
        {
            temp = 20;
        }
        else if (x.equals("U"))
        {
            temp = 21;
        }
        else if (x.equals("V"))
        {
            temp = 22;
        }
        else if (x.equals("W"))
        {
            temp = 23;
        }
        else if (x.equals("X"))
        {
            temp = 24;
        }
        else if (x.equals("Y"))
        {
            temp = 25;
        }
        else if (x.equals("Z"))
        {
            temp = 26;
        }
        else if (x.equals("Qwerty"))
        {
            temp = 27;
        }
    }
    public static void evaluate()
    {
        if(temp>=1 && temp<= 6)
        {
            answer =  (temp * 3)/4;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + answer);
        }
        else if(temp >= 7 && temp<= 10)
        {
            answer = (temp/3) + 25;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + answer);
        }
        else if(temp >= 11 && temp<= 14)
        {

        }

        else if(temp>=15 && temp<= 17)
        {
            for(int i = temp; i>0; i--)
            {
                for(int j = 2; j <=i/2 + 1; j++)
                {
                    if(i%j==0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if(j==i/2 + 1)
                    {
                    answer = i * 3;
                    }           
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Answer is " + answer);
        }
        else if(temp>=18 && temp<= 23)
        {
            answer = temp;
        }
        else if(temp>= 24 && temp<=26)

            answer = (answer * 12)%26;
            System.out.println("Answer is " + answer);
            }
    }
```

-Corruption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better approach for char to int conversion:
Assuming the string has at least 1 character(check for its length), you can get the temp by doing:

```
temp = x.getCharAt(0) - 'A' + 1;
```

or, safety first:

```
temp = 0;
if (x.matches("^[A-Z]{1}$") {
  temp = x.getCharAt(0) - 'A' + 1;
}
```

What's happening here? Every character has an ASCII code, an integer. So, when you have 2 chars and you try to get the distance between them, the result is an int. `'A' - 'A' = 0`(that's why i added a `+ 1`), `'B' - 'A' = 1` and so on.
For the if condition, I am using a `RegExp`. `^` means start of the input, `[A-Z]{1}` means one of  A-Z, `$` means the end of the input. So, if it's an A-Z, temp will get a value, anything else won't make it in the if and your `temp` will remain 0 so you can easily test if you've got an A-Z or not.

That's all for code review, I won't give you solutions, you must work harder, use Google. You won't enjoy and learn if I give you everything ready for a copy paste.